# Как перебрать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

В массиве есть три объекта (в данном случае). Подскажите что мне сделать что бы я мог спокойно пройтись по каждому из них `for` циклом, взять значения некоторых ключей, ибо если я пытаюсь сделать это и вывести получившееся в консоль сейчас получаю вот что

```
1499204237
1499204238
```

Вот пример того, что у меня есть.

```
callback([
  {
      "time": "1499204237",
      "user": "Mikus",
  },
  {
      "time": "1499204238",
      "user": "Rex",
  },
  {
      "time": "1499204239",
      "user": "Nik"
  }
]);
$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
function callback(respond) {
for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];
    var time = new Array(data.time);
        for(var j = 0; j < time.length; j++){
            //какие-то действия
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что я получаю когда просто вывожу в консоль переменную `time`

```
["1499204237"]
["1499204238"]
```

В консоли их можно развернуть(см. фото).Я пытался так же сделать так

`time[0]`

То есть попытался взять нулевое значение, но проблема в том что все массивы в этой переменной хранят значения в `[0]`(см.фото). Подскажите, что мне делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Есть три массива" - нет трех массивов. Ох, как Вам надо учиться задавать вопросы! :(

Comment: @Igor Прошу прощения, а как правильно сказать?

Comment: Представьте, что мы **вообще** ничего не знаем про Ваш код. Представили? Начинайте формулировать вопрос.

Comment: Что такое `data`? Функция?

Comment: @Igor Нет, взгляните обновленные вопрос. Исправил всё что знаю.

Comment: Как вызывается функция `callback`? Какой смысл ее параметра `respond`?

Comment: @Igor Callback вызывается когда я беру с файла все то, что я написал в `data`. А в respond содержится непосредственно содержание файла с которого я и взял массив объектов, потом я прохожусь по нему циклом и помещаю `respond[i]` в `data`.Добавлю это в вопрос.

Comment: очень хорошо, дело начинает проясняться. Объясните теперь, зачем Вам нужен массив `time` (с одним элементом `data.time`) внутри цикла.

Comment: @Igor Мне нужно вообще просто пройтись по всем `time`  в файле и определить какие мне подходят. Для этого я думал циклом пройтись по каждому из них и если находится подходящее то я его вывожу на экран.

Comment: Код в ответе Вас устраивает?

Comment: @Igor Почти. Скажите как мне написать цикл в котором от каждого  `time` будет  отниматься, скажем, 10000, т.е. `1499204237 - 10000`, `1499204238 - 10000`?

Comment: отниматься и куда сохраняться? Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function callback(respond) {
  for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];
    //какие-то действия с data.user и data.time
    data.time = data.time - 10000;
    console.log(data);
  }
}

var d = [
  {
    "time": "1499204237",
    "user": "Mikus"
  },
  {
    "time": "1499204238",
    "user": "Rex"
  },
  {
    "time": "1499204239",
    "user": "Nik"
  }
];

callback(d);
```